# Changing <label for>

Tags: javascript, forms, sharepoint

I'm working in SharePoint 2013 list that has a Choice column with the "Allow 'Fill-in' choices:" set to Yes.

By default, the text label for that radio button is set to "Specify your own value:" and it can't be changed through the user interface.  How can it be changed via JS?  I've provide a short snippet below of what the final rendered code looks like.

```
<span title="Specify your own value:" class="ms-RadioText" onclick="SetFocusOnControl('ctl00_m_g_d8db5d84_c3de_40e0_8fa4_d9fd909d75d1_ff1251_ctl00_ctl02')">
    <input name="ctl00$m$g_d8db5d84_c3de_40e0_8fa4_d9fd909d75d1$ff1251$ctl00$RadioButtons" id="ctl00_m_g_d8db5d84_c3de_40e0_8fa4_d9fd909d75d1_ff1251_ctl00_ctl01" type="radio" value="ctl01">
    <label for="ctl00_m_g_d8db5d84_c3de_40e0_8fa4_d9fd909d75d1_ff1251_ctl00_ctl01">Specify your own value:
    </label>
</span>
```

Here's what I've tried but was unsuccessful:

```
document.getElementByName("ctl00$m$g_d8db5d84_c3de_40e0_8fa4_d9fd909d75d1$ff1251$ctl00$RadioButtons")[1].innerHTML="BOO!";
document.getElementByName("ctl00$m$g_d8db5d84_c3de_40e0_8fa4_d9fd909d75d1$ff1251$ctl00$RadioButtons")[1].innerText="BOO!";
document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_d8db5d84_c3de_40e0_8fa4_d9fd909d75d1_ff1251_ctl00_ctl01")[1].innerText="BOO!";
document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_d8db5d84_c3de_40e0_8fa4_d9fd909d75d1_ff1251_ctl00_ctl01")[1].innerHTML="BOO!";
```

Thanks,

-Haniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByName` works for elements with `name` attributes. Similarly, `getElementById` works for elements with `id` attributes. So, since the label has neither, those won't work.

What you need is

```JavaScript
document.querySelector('label[for="ridiculouslylongid"]').innerHTML="BOO!";
```

Also, you have `[1]` in both the functions in your source, but that's not OK. For `getElementsByName` you should have used `[0]`, because the result is 0-based. For `getElementById`, as for `querySelector`, you won't need an index at all (they're not collections).

Comment: Hi Mr Lister, Thanks for your help.  I keep getting an error that it's a null object.  The ID matches that of the label.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Haniel That's strange. I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/aa8Lu61e/1/) from your source where it works, as you can see. Are you sure that you're calling the JavaScript at the right moment, after the label already exists? Also, in which browser?

Comment: Hi again, after some investigation I was able to get it to work by placing the script block next to the control as opposed to at the top or bottom of the page.